# Water sprays out between handle and hose

Tags: water

[image]

Hey guys, I hope those who read this can help. Water has recently begun spraying out at the handle. I've tried tightening it, and no difference. I thought it was the handle, so I replaced it. The same issue happens with the new one. I thought it was the hose, so I replaced it. The same issue with the new one. I don't know what has changed in the past week for this to happen all of a sudden, but I am tired of getting drenched just watering the stupid plants. Thanks!

Comment: you water pressure is likely up the last week if there's less landscaping and ag water consumption...

Answer (score 1):

The typical hose end (female) also includes a rubber washer that mates with the inside of the fitting and th end of the handle. They wear, they age, they get lost. (should I have used semicolons? That's another SE)

Easily determined to be missing. Look into the hose end. If you see the washer, replace it. If you don't see the washer, hop over to the hardware store of choice and ask for a hose end washer.

[image: hose washers]

The washers are going to be varied in color and some may not have the tiny ears that allow them to listen to water flow. Not really, the ears keep them from falling out, as they will push beyond the threads and hold the washer in place. You probably have to buy three or four or five, use one and lose the rest in the clutter when you need them again. No, wait. That's me.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I took a look at each part for washers, and found them on the facet and the connecter to the hose hideaway box, not in between handle and hose. I don't remember washer between handle and hose, but I can get some at Lowes and see if it helps.

Comment: I apologize it has taken so long to reply with the final result. It was a washer issue. I picked up a pack at Lowes, and popped one in to which provided success at first use. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you replaced the handle, it likely came with a new washer.  We have a hose that leaks even with new washers because the male metal threaded fitting on the end of the hose is cracked a bit at the opening.  You will also get a leak if the metal hose fitting is oval because it was stepped on or hammered.